# Spark Dataframe to Dataset of Java class

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I want to transform a Dataframe that is read in as Json to a Dataset of a given class. So far, that worked pretty well, when I was able to write own case classes.

```
case class MyCaseClass(...)
val df = spark.read.json("path/to/json")
val ds = df.as[MyCaseClass]

def myFunction(input: MyCaseClass): MyCaseClass = {
    // Do some validation and things
    input
}

ds.map(myFunction)
```

However, now I am bound to external Java classes (specifically ones created by thrift). So here a more concrete example with a custom class:

Json:

```
{"a":1,"b":"1","wrapper":{"inside":"1.1", "map": {"k": "v"}}}
{"a":2,"b":"2","wrapper":{"inside":"2.1", "map": {"k": "v"}}}
{"a":3,"b":"3","wrapper":{"inside":"3.1", "map": {"k": "v"}}}
```

Class:

```
class MyInnerClass(var inside: String, var map: Map[String, String]) extends java.io.Serializable {
  def getInside(): String = {inside}
  def setInside(newInside: String) {inside = newInside}
  def getMap(): Map[String, String] = {map}
  def setMap(newMap: Map[String, String]) {map = newMap}
}

class MyClass(var a: Int, var b: String, var wrapper: MyInnerClass)  extends java.io.Serializable {
  def getA(): Int = {a}
  def setA(newA: Int) {a = newA}
  def getB(): String = {b}
  def setB(newB: String) {b = newB}
  def getWrapper(): MyInnerClass = {wrapper}
  def setWrapper(newWrapper: MyInnerClass) {wrapper = newWrapper}
}
```

So I want to do:

```
val json = spark.read.json("path/to/json")
json.as[MyClass]
```

However, that throws:

```
Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive type (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
```

So, I found out about Custom Encoders: ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-a-dataset) and [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-Encoder.html))

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
val kryoMyClassEncoder  = Encoders.kryo[MyClass]
json.as[MyClass](kryoMyClassEncoder)
```

Which throws:

```
Try to map struct<a:bigint,b:string,wrapper:struct<inside:string,map:struct<k:string>>> to Tuple1, but failed as the number of fields does not line up
```

So how can I convert a Dataframe to a custom object Dataset.

Comment: Any luck on that? Could you please share how you got it working?

Comment: Same problem here. I have a workaround using Java classes (and enums), but I would love to see it working with Scala classes and enums as well.

Comment: I faced the same issue in a similar context. In my case, I had the case class created in the same method where I was reading the JSON. I moved the case class definition to an outer scope and it curiously worked. Serendipitously I  stumbled upon this solution while browsing for [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704831/value-todf-is-not-a-member-of-org-apache-spark-rdd-rdd) error.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using kryo encoder, try using the product encoder, ie:

```
val productMyClassEncoder  = Encoders.product[MyClass]
```

Comment: Worked for me only when I both used the product encoder and moved the case class definition into an outer scope

Answer (score 1):

Same problem i had(nothing helped) when used **declaration of case class inside method**. After moving the class outside the method `import spark.implicits._` worked correctly

Answer (score 1):

While reading the data as json, we need to change the schema to a single field with type Binary and column name as "value" when using kryo serialization

```
val json = spark.read.json("path/to/json").schema(newStructType().add("value",BinaryType))
```