# Spark incorrect serialization of nested structs on group-reduce by key

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to reduce data frame by key. The reduce logic is pretty complex and requires update on about 10-15 fields. That why I want to convert DataFrame to DataSet and reduce Java POJOs.

### Problem

The problem is that after `groupByKey-reduceByKey` I got some very strange values. `Encoders.bean(Entity.class)` reads correct data. *See Code Example section*.

### Workarrounds

Replacing `Encoders.bean` with `Encoders.kryo` does not work, exception:

`Try to map struct<broker_name:string,server_name:string,order:int,storages:array<struct<timestamp:timestamp,storage:double>>> to Tuple1, but failed as the number of fields does not line up.`

Also I saw [this workarround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41876965/spark-dataframe-to-dataset-of-java-class), but `Encoders.product` requires `TypeTag` . I have no idea how to create `TypeTag` at Java code.

### Code Example

```
    Dataset<Entity> ds = createDataFrame("testData.json", "testSchema.json")
        .as(Encoders.bean(Entity.class));

    // shows correct numbers
    ds.show(10, false);

    // correct data, please pay attention to `storages` column values
+-----------+-----------+-----+-------------------------------+
|broker_name|server_name|order|storages                       |
+-----------+-----------+-----+-------------------------------+
|A1         |S1         |1    |[[2018-10-29 23:11:44, 12.5]]  |
|A2         |S1         |1    |[[2018-10-30 14:43:05, 13.2]]  |
|A3         |S1         |2    |[[2019-11-02 10:00:03, 1001.0]]|
+-----------+-----------+-----+-------------------------------+


    //after reduce shows wrong numbers
    ds
        .groupByKey(o -> new RowKey(o.getBroker_name(), o.getServer_name(), o.getOrder()), Encoders.bean(RowKey.class))
        .reduceGroups((e1, e2) -> e1)
        .map(tuple -> tuple._2, Encoders.bean(Entity.class))
        .show(10, false);

    // wrong values, please pay attention to `storages` column
+-----------+-----+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|broker_name|order|server_name|storages                                                 |
+-----------+-----+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|A1         |2    |S1         |[[7.77011509161492E-309, 149386-07-09 23:48:5454.211584]]|
|A1         |1    |S1         |[[7.61283374479283E-309, 148474-03-19 21:14:3232.5248]]  |
+-----------+-----+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

*Entity.java*

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Entity implements Serializable {
    private String broker_name;
    private String server_name;
    private Integer order;
    private Storage[] storages;
}
```

*Storage.java*

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Storage implements Serializable {
    private Timestamp timestamp;
    private Double storage;
}
```

*testData.json:*

```
[
  {
    "broker_name": "A1",
    "server_name": "S1",
    "order": 1,
    "storages": [
      {
        "timestamp": "2018-10-29 23:11:44.000",
        "storage": 12.5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "broker_name": "A1",
    "server_name": "S1",
    "order": 1,
    "storages": [
      {
        "timestamp": "2018-10-30 14:43:05.000",
        "storage": 13.2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "broker_name": "A1",
    "server_name": "S1",
    "order": 2,
    "storages": [
      {
        "timestamp": "2019-11-02 10:00:03.000",
        "storage": 1001.0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

*testSchema.json:*

```
{
  "type": "struct",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "broker_name",
      "type": "string",
      "nullable": true,
      "metadata": {}
    },
    {
      "name": "server_name",
      "type": "string",
      "nullable": true,
      "metadata": {}
    },
    {
      "name": "order",
      "type": "integer",
      "nullable": true,
      "metadata": {}
    },
    {
      "name": "storages",
      "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "elementType": {
          "type": "struct",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "timestamp",
              "type": "timestamp",
              "nullable": true,
              "metadata": {}
            },
            {
              "name": "storage",
              "type": "double",
              "nullable": true,
              "metadata": {}
            }
          ]
        },
        "containsNull": true
      },
      "nullable": true,
      "metadata": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because deserialization uses structural matching on schema inferred by the `Encoder`, and since bean classes have no natural structure, fields of the schema are ordered by name.

So if you define a bean class like your `Entity`, the schema inferred from the bean `Encoder` will be

```java
Encoders.bean(Storage.class).schema().printTreeString();
```

```
root
 |-- storage: double (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

not

```
root
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- storage: double (nullable = true)
```

and this the schema that should be used the `Dataset`. In other words schema defined as:

```
StructType schema = Encoders.bean(Entity.class).schema();
```

or

```
StructType schema = StructType.fromDDL(
  "broker_name string, order integer, server_name string, " + 
  "storages array<struct<storage: double, timestamp: timestamp>>" 
);
```

would be valid, and could be used to load `testData` directly:

```
Dataset<Entity> ds = spark.read()
  .option("multiline", "true")
  .schema(schema)
  .json("testData.json")
  .as(Encoders.bean(Entity.class));
```

while your current schema, which is equivalent to:

```
StructType valid = StructType.fromDDL(
  "broker_name string, order integer, server_name string, " + 
  "storages array<struct<timestamp: timestamp, storage: double>>" 
);
```

is not, despite the fact that it would work with JSON reader, which (in contrast to `Encoders`), matches data by name.

Arguably this behavior should be reported as a bug - intuitively there should be no case where `Encoder` dumps data that is incompatible with it's own loading logic.

Related JIRA ticket - [SPARK-27050](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27050)